Does a 2.5" SATA SSD fit into a 2.5" SATA HDD slot in a desktop computer?
My desktop computer manufactured in 2019 supports one or two 2.5" SATA HDDs configuration. The manual mentions nothing about 2.5" SATA SSD. Can I safely assume that a 2.5" SATA SSD will fit in?

that's the whole point of making SSDs the same size as HDDs

@CriticizingSEisbannable Glad to know!

If you haven't bought the SATA SSD yet, note that NVMe SSDs (+ an NVMe PCI Express card, if your PC does not have an M.2 slot) are also an option.

NVMe SSDs are fast. SATA SSDs are designed for compatibility with hard drives. They're also fast, but without SATA they get extremely fast.

Yeah, it'll physically fit. With a desktop you don't even need to worry about z height I suspect, and a SSD's likely the 'common' thinner standard.
In most cases, assuming OS support (so anything Windows 7 and onwards, most current Linux's etc) it'll just work.

The latter is not always the case. I encountered a laptop computer once which was behaving very erratic when we replaced a HDD with some Kingston SSD (and Windows 7). That SSD now works fine in some old PC of mine (running Linux); I am sure it is good. The motivation to replace was that original HDD in the laptop failed, and there was a suggestion to "upgrade" it to SSD, but it didn't go well. But then we installed another HDD in it that laptop and it works fine, so laptop is good too. Too bad, I never had a chance to investigate that incompatibility further.

@NikitaKipriyanov – I've seen an old laptop that refused to work properly with an SSD in place of its old HDD, be brought back into compliance with a BIOS update (it hadn't been updated since purchase, there had been a couple of major releases in the year or so after that time). The issue might not have been unique to SSDs – it is conceivable that some “traditional” drives could also have been unreliable in the machine due to whatever issue the update fixed. It is also worth checking to see if the OS is behind with any storage related driver updates.

No, you can't blindly assume it'll work.  Unlike 3.5" drives, 2.5" drives come in a range of heights, ranging from 5mm to 19mm.
Most 2.5" hard drives are 9.5mm high, while most SSDs are 7mm high.  Most desktop 2.5" drive bays are open-top, open-back and can handle any 2.5" drive, but occasionally you'll find a slot bay designed for one specific height of drive (usually 9.5mm).

Thanks for the detailed answer! I think the most accurate description is "In most cases you can, but occasionally you can't."

I might change "most" to "many"; I have had several laptops that originally came with HDDs that have a 7 mm bay, and I also have had several 9.5 mm SSDs that won't fit into them.

the side and bottom holes in 2.5 inch drives of any height should align with any other size. You can't fit a taller drive into a slimmer caddy or bay, but I can't image the other way around. The only modern 2.5 inch drives I've seen with taller z height are 5tb externals, and I guess server 2.5 inch drives

@JourneymanGeek, I once encountered a tool-free design that required pressure on the top of the drive to hold the side brackets in place.  Put a 7mm drive in, and the brackets would spread apart and the drive would fall to the bottom of the case.

ah! Years ago, I'd seen spacers for that sorta thing
